# How do i fix invalid column name in sql

Tags: c#

I'm a beginner in SQL and c#. I'm trying to create a system that will lead the user to eligibility form if they have not done it before, but an error that says invalid column name keeps popping.

```
string query = "select * from Eligibility where Name = " + textBox1.Text;
sql.Open();
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, sql);
SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

if (dr.Read())
{
     label6.Text = (dr["name"].ToString());
}

sql.Dispose();

if (label6.Text == textBox1.Text)
{
     this.Hide();
     UserHomeView uhv = new UserHomeView();
     uhv.Show();
}
else
{
     this.Hide();
     Eligibility eli = new Eligibility();
     eli.Show();
}
```

Comment: Don't concatenate sql together, use parameters and sql issue's wont be as prone as well as possible injection. Wrap commands and connections in `using` statements to properly dispose of them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You missed the single quotation

```
string query = "select * from Eligibility where Name = '" + textBox1.Text + "'";
```

Even so, there is some serious problem with the above code. This can cause a serious sql injection problem for you [Check wikipedia entry on this](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)

It's better to use the add parameters function which will sanitize the input and make it safe for you to execute the query.

The best solution would be something like this

```
    string query = "select * from Eligibility where Name = @Name";
    sql.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, sql);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Name", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = textBox1.Text;
```

This way, your query will be injection safe.

Comment: I'd immediately enter `bla'; drop table eligibility; --` ;)

Comment: @Sinatr this is where hopefully besides using parameters, proper roles have been setup...

Comment: Good point @Sinatr, that's why I added the Parameters.Add option.

Comment: Remove the last line o code. Change the 2nd to last line to this; `cmd.Parameters.Add("@Name", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = textBox1.Text;`. Then you have a working answer.

Comment: Cheers! Good spot

Answer (score 2):

Just to build on what others have said:

Once you're comfy with doing things this way check out Stored Procedures.

Stored Procedures lets you save the query in the database and all you do on the c# side is call the Stored Procedure and add the required parameters.

These tend to be a better way of doing this as you can then learn about how to restrict access to your database for only certain users and also it means the Query itself is in an environment that will check for mistakes as well.

This is a good article as an introduction to them:

http://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-stored-procedures/

Answer (score 0):

You can use Parameters of SqlCommand, like this:

```
string query = "select * from Eligibility where Name = @Name";
            sql.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, sql);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Name", SqlDbType.Text);
        cmd.Parameters["@Name"].Value = textBox1.Text;
            SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        if (dr.Read())
        {
            label6.Text = (dr["name"].ToString());
        }
            sql.Dispose();
            if (label6.Text == textBox1.Text)
                {
                    this.Hide();
                    UserHomeView uhv = new UserHomeView();
                    uhv.Show();
                }
                else
                {
                    this.Hide();
                    Eligibility eli = new Eligibility();
                    eli.Show();
                }
```